# Correct expression to compare variable in XSLT

Tags: variables, xslt

Goal is to output "test" when info variable is set to "full". What am I doing wrong here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>

                <!-- Set Variable-->
                <xsl:variable name="info" select="full" />

                <!-- Test-->
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$info = 'full'">
                        <p>test</p>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <p>test 2</p>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>


            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm looking for a simple solution to compare variable and do something based if it's true or not. Simple example yet it always outputs test2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable selects an **element** named `full` in the input XML - not a **string** containing the characters `"full"`.

You test would return true if your input happened to be:

**XML**

```
<full>full</full>
```

Try instead:

```
<xsl:variable name="info" select='"full"' />
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine, thank you. I misunderstood how variables works in XSLT...